# How can i connect openshift git repository to bitbucket

Tags: git, openshift, bitbucket

I've created a project on Red Hat openshift now i want to know about how can i connect it with my bit-bucket account to maintain and handle my openshift Project
with bit-bucket

Comment: I read the comment below and i feel that the comment / answers are not the actual answer to your and mine thoughts . so if you've done this thing , can you please share the knowledge with me

Answer (score 8):

**Clone your current repo to your computer,**

```
git clone {{ ssh:source_code }}
```

The source code URL is available in the app  console (under source code) 
ex:

```
git clone ssh://555065b53433ca08f100001b@appname-domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/example.git/
```

log in to bitbucket, create a new repo, with type as `git` .

navigate your terminal to the cloned repo,

**Adding remote to the cloned repo**

```
git remote add bitbucket https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
```

**To push the changes to the remote repo on `bitbucket`,**

```
git push bitbucket { branch }
```

example:

```
git push bitbucket master
```

**To push the changes to OpenShift repo,**

```
git push origin {branch}
```