# Unable to associate bit bucket in OpenShift (Updating in 2 Places Now)

Tags: openshift

I deployed an application in Openshift and now its running.

I have committed the changes to Openshift git repository (example:
  ssh://xxxx61@mydemo.rhcloud.com/~/git/mydemo.git/)

I have the project in bit bucket. Since not sure how to sync or authorize the bit bucket i have commited in the above.

I would like to sync or authorize bit bucket, so that whenever i check-in the changes in the bit bucket, the changes will be taken by the openshift.

Could you please help me on how to authorize or sync or associate the bit bucket project in openshift instead of committing in 2 places?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i connect openshift git repository to bitbucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262990/how-can-i-connect-openshift-git-repository-to-bitbucket)

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to "sync" BitBucket with an OpenShit repo. You can however always push automatically (`git push --all`) to both places as you've mentioned.

If required, here's the topic on setting two remotes:
[How can i connect openshift git repository to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262990/how-can-i-connect-openshift-git-repository-to-bitbucket)